# Javascript responsive video height/width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-video

I want to make a fullscreen-video responsive landing page. I have a video (1920x1080) which is centered. But when I resize the window, it's not resizing properly. Javascript solution only please.

Example how it should look like: http://www.welcometofillory.com/
I appreciate any help.

Javascript so far:

```
var $vid = $('.full-screen-video');

    updateSize();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        updateSize();
    });

    function updateSize() {

        var $eWidth = window.innerWidth;

        var $AspectRatio = 1080 / 1920;

        var $newHeight = $eWidth * $AspectRatio;

        $vid.css({"width": $eWidth, "height": $newHeight});


    };
```

Comment: The code should resize the target element i.e. `.full-screen-video` upon window resize. There must be logic error somewhere else.

Comment: its resizing the video but its calculating the wrong width, height. i have black borders on smaller devices

Comment: The padding you find is vertical or horizontal?

Comment: both vertical and horizontal

Comment: :/ okay now only vertical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is true. Use console to see the process:

```
function updateSize() {

    var $eWidth = window.innerWidth;

    var $AspectRatio = 1080 / 1920;

    var $newHeight = $eWidth * $AspectRatio;

    console.log('eWidth: ' + eWidth);
    console.log('newHeight: ' + newHeight); 

    $vid.css({"width": $eWidth, "height": $newHeight});

    console.log('real width' + $('.full-screen-video').width());
    console.log('real height' + $('.full-screen-video').height());
};
```

And you can test this css rule:

```
.full-screen-video {
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc(100vw / 1.7);  /* 1.7 is 1920/1080 */
 }
```

Comment: To use css rule you must remove javascript codes changing the size. Did you do that?

Comment: yes. i only have vertical padding now. with the javascript code. dont know how to fix that :/

Comment: Probabley that is not vertical padding, You set the fixed height to video, Decrease the height of browser to see if vertical padding will remove?

Comment: yes the border removes when i decrease the height of browser

Comment: So every thing is OK! You set a fixed height for video and it worked! If you do not want this set the height of video to `100vh` or `100%`.

Comment: works with css only: .full-screen-video {
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px;
    max-width: 1920px;
    max-height: 1080px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

Answer (score 0):

works using css only:

```
<div class="fullsize-container">
    <video autoplay id="landing-video" class="full-screen-video" width="100%" height="100%" preload="auto" loop="loop">
        <source src="assets/landing-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

.fullsize-container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.full-screen-video {
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px;
    max-width: 1920px;
    max-height: 1080px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```